# android-soda-client not found in Maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, client, soda

Hi I am following the directions in https://github.com/socrata/soda-android-sdk to include the android-soda-client as a gradle/maven dependency in my build.gradle, but the dependency is not resolved.  I looked in the Maven Repository for com.socrata and didnt see the dependency in there either.  Does this mean that the library has to be built from source for each Android app?

Comment: Looks that way. Well you just need to build it the first time. Once it's built, you can reuse that artifact.